# UItableview with two sets of options

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which shows slightly different content depending on the type of user. So one is a list of options for a dog-owner and another for dog-walker. Some options are the same. What’s the best way of doing this is one table view controller?

```
Name
Address
My walkers
My dogs
```

```
Name
Address
My customers
Walking qualifications
```

(In real life, these tables are much longer)

Answer (score 0):

Create two different tableview cells and change the cell based on the type of user. This is one way of doing.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if dataSource[indexPath.item].isFirstuser {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: “type1”, for: indexPath) as! type1Cell
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        cell.model = model
        return cell
      } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: “type2”, for: indexPath) as! type2Cell
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        cell.model = model
        return cell
       }   
}
```

Comment: Another solution is use of stack views,it is possible only the different between the user cells more similar. Hide/unhide ui components based on the user type.

Comment: let me know if you found any other best solution.